# How much does the first place in a contest actually depend on yourself?

Tags: probability

Let's say a person is participating to a contest, or is the member of any kind of group (athletes, school class, ...)

If the number of people in the same group is 'n', how much of the probability of being the first of that group for that challenge/test/race does actually depend on the person itself, and not on the results of his peers ?

What I mean, is that if we suppose the considered person has a certain level in the tested skill, if it happens that all of the other people are of inferior level, it makes that person the first, without this person doing any effort whatsoever (presumably).

I hope the question is clear

EDIT: Please do make any necessary assumptions or additional hypotheses needed to answer, such as a probable distribution of the skills among the group, and so on.

Comment: Well: if you are the only who competes you are bound to win.
Else I, personally, would go with the idea of the Normal Distribution, in other words the more people you take the more you will have a great percentage which is around the average [Law of Big Numbers], whereas if you only allow a small amount of partecipants then results can really vary depending on the test subjects...

Comment: sure, but how could it be expressed mathematically depending on the 'n' number of participants ?

Comment: yes it can but you first have to define some paremeters, I mean: a kind of function of distribution who assigns a skill to every person based on some kind of paremeters. Then you take a group of individuals which again must be defined by even more traits, and then you can evaluate mathematically what the possible results are [expected value, standard deviation and so on].

Take for example the rolling of a dice: the more you roll it the more each value will have appeared at a ratio of $1/6$ yet if you throw it less than 10 times your distribution can be extremely poorly pondered...

Comment: well, I guess that if you take an academical example (school class), the distribution would be gaussian ? regarding the rest, sorry but I'm not sure to understand which other traits I would need to define ? (not a math expert at all)

Comment: well it would most probably be Gaussian, Normal for instance.
Basically what you have to do is to have a function that describes the probability of a single event to happen. Then you assume that n of these events occurr and you look at the way the distribution behaves according to an increasing n...

Answer (score 1):

My daughter swims.  For younger kids in our circuit, the 7- and 8-year-olds swim against each other, and the 9- and 10-year-olds swim against each other.

She turned 9 recently.  She's had her last meet as an 8-year-old.  She placed in a number of events (a) primarily because she works hard, but also because (b) she was one of the oldest swimmers competing there.

In her next meet, she'll be in quite a different position in the distribution, because she'll be one of the youngest swimmers.

The term you used in your question speaks volumes:  **peers**.  Peers can be according to skill level (which they are in swimming, later, through the use of "cut times") or by age.  Individual skill is just relative, and it's relative to the population of one's peers that one has worked (or aged) their way into.  Then, you can say something about whether an individual is below average, above average, or one in 10,000.

My daughter is a member of the 9- and 10-year-old population of swimmers.  She's not a member of the US Olympic Swim Team.  So comparing her times alongside those of Olympic Swimmers doesn't make any sense.  They're not even part of the distribution.  Just like Michael Phelps' times wouldn't be considered valid at my daughter's swim meets.

It's all about performance relative to an appropriate population.  If you're the best, then you're the best *in that population*.